# google cloud sub-modules are not recognized in VS code python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, import

In VS code, when I using `from google.cloud import xxxx`, it gave me an error that xxx is unknown import symbol. But the code can run without any issue, as the packages are actually installed. But it is fine to use `from google.cloud.xxx import yyyy`. As shown below.
[image: import error]

Even the code can run, it is just very annoying to show this error. Does anyone know how this can be fixed? I am using the latest version of VS code (1.80.1) and Pylance (v2023.7.20).

Thanks!